# Como comparar dados com acentos na base de dados?

Tags: php, mysql

Estou com o problema numa pesquisa que fiz em que o utilizador filtro conteúdo por distrito e concelho, está a funcionar bem quando escolho distrito e concelho sem acentos mas quando escolho um distrito e um concelho que contém acentos não me devolve qualquer valores gostaria de saber como posso resolver situação ?

PHP

```
$result_categoria = mysql_query("select * from categorias_estabelecimentos where      categoria_slug='".$categoria."'");
while($row_categoria = mysql_fetch_object($result_categoria)){
$result_local=mysql_query("select * from estabelecimentos where id='".$row_categoria->estabelecimento_id."' and distritos='".$distritos."' and concelhos='".$concelhos."' and activo=1");
while($row_local=mysql_fetch_object($result_local)){
    if(mysql_num_rows($result_local)>0){
        $result_anexo_local=mysql_query("select * from estabelecimentos_anexos where id_mae='".$row_local->id."' and seccao='thumbnail'");
        $row_anexo_local=mysql_fetch_object($result_anexo_local);
```

Comment: Qual é a *collation* usada na sua tabela?

Comment: utf8_unicode_ci

Comment: Tente com `LIKE` então: `... and distritos LIKE '".$distritos."' and concelhos LIKE '".$concelhos."' and ...`

Comment: tentei como disse Não resolveu

Comment: Qual o caracter set? utf-8?

Comment: Tente implementar esta função no seu banco de dados https://gist.github.com/williamurbano/f4c8d23a0e0d21622334

Answer (score 2):

A solução ideal é a BD ser accent insensitive. Alterar o formato é viável?

Pode requerer repopular a base de dados e dar trabalho, mas já me aconteceu esse problema no passado e ir fazendo workarounds é um pesadelo, pois vão surgindo novas situações que causam problemas.

Answer (score 0):

Não sei como seria exatamente no php, mas... vai uma sugestão.

- Monte um array com todos os caracteres que queira avaliar:
  CaracteresEspeciais = ['Á', 'á', 'É', 'é', .. 'Ç', 'ç'];
- Compare cada caracter de seu string com seus CaracteresEspeciais e faça as alterações necessárias.

Answer (score 0):

Recomendo a você dar uma olhada na documentação do PHP e procurar as funções `utf8_encode` e `utf8_decode`. Quando for enviar uma string pro BD, force o encoding correto nela com `utf8_encode` e quando for recuperar uma string, aplique `utf8_decode` antes de executar a comparação.

Exemplo:

```
$string_acentuada = "Olá!";
$string_utf8 = utf8_encode($string_acentuada);
echo $string_acentuada." - Encoding do sistema\r\n";
echo $string_utf8." - Encoding UTF8\r\n";
if(utf8_decode($string_utf8) == $string_acentuada)
    echo "São iguais!";
```