# Como comparar valores na base de dados com acentos?

Tags: php, mysql

Boas,

Estou com o problema numa pesquisa que fiz em que o utilizador filtro conteúdo por distrito e concelho, está a funcionar bem quando escolho distrito e concelho sem acentos mas quando escolho um distrito e um concelho que contém acentos não me devolve qualquer valores gostaria de saber como posso resolver situação ?

PHP

```
$result_categoria = mysql_query("select * from categorias_estabelecimentos where      categoria_slug='".$categoria."'");
while($row_categoria = mysql_fetch_object($result_categoria)){
$result_local=mysql_query("select * from estabelecimentos where id='".$row_categoria->estabelecimento_id."' and distritos='".$distritos."' and concelhos='".$concelhos."' and activo=1");
while($row_local=mysql_fetch_object($result_local)){
    if(mysql_num_rows($result_local)>0){
        $result_anexo_local=mysql_query("select * from estabelecimentos_anexos where id_mae='".$row_local->id."' and seccao='thumbnail'");
        $row_anexo_local=mysql_fetch_object($result_anexo_local);
```

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51165/problema-ao-comparar-string-com-acentos-mysql ??

Comment: Sim e esse o problema nem me lembrava que já tinha colocado esse post mas de qualquer forma não consegui resolver das sugestões que colocaram lá

Comment: Mas não é o caso de repostar. Se a pergunta continua a mesma, você pode editar a outra, e ela volta a aparecer na primeira página do site. Vou fechar esta como duplicata ok?

Comment: Claro que sim tem toda a razão eu já nem me lembrava que já tinha colocado sobre o caso sim pode apagar. obrigado

Comment: Editei a outra pergunta e não veio para primeiro na pagina

Comment: Não é instantâneo, mas está lá agora.