# Como comparar string com acentos no php

Tags: php, mysql

Possuo um problema que não consegui resolver no php, tenho um campo `varchar` no `MySQL` com acentuação, faço resgate da mesma e uso o `htmlentities` para que a string fique com a acentuação correta.
Preciso comparar a variável vindo do banco e marcar um campo radio se a condição for verdadeira, mas não estou conseguindo, o que tenho e isso:

Resgate da variável:

```
$Motivo = htmlentities($row_DocContratacao['MotivoContratacao']);
```

Comparação do valor

```
<input type="radio" name="Motivo" id="motivo-4" value="Recontratação"<?php if ($Motivo=="Recontratação") echo ' checked="checked"'; ?> />
```

O valor resgatado é `Recontratação` mas o campo radio não fica marcado.

Comment: Podes também retirar os acentos e fazer a comparação sem acentos.

Comment: Olá @Earendul, mas não entendi o porque não consegui fazer a comparação com acentuação.

Comment: a condição não combina porque ao aplicar `htmlentities` a comparação fica `'Recontrata&ccedil;&atilde;o' == 'Recontratação'`, remover a chamada de `htmlentities` deve resolver o problema

Comment: possível duplicata de [Como comparar dados com acentos na base de dados?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51165/como-comparar-dados-com-acentos-na-base-de-dados)

Comment: Olá @Sanção, no meu caso, com o htmlentities consigo resgatar a variável com a acentuação correta, mas não consigo compara-lo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao usar o htmlentities vc estará mudando a String para "Recontrata& ccedil;& atilde;o" que quando for comparada a "Recontrataç& atilde;o" vai te retornar um boolen false.

Tente converter dentro de seu IF para obter o resultado esperado, segue abaixo um exemplo de como fazer.

```
<input type="radio" name="Motivo" id="motivo-4" value="Recontratação"<?php if ($Motivo==htmlentities("Recontratação")) echo ' checked="checked"'; ?> />
```

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda.